# pip install tensorflow getting stuck in download

Tags: python, tensorflow, installation, pip

On my windows 10 machine I am trying:

```
pip --default-timeout=5000 install tensorflow
```

It gets stuck at different places at different times but never succeeding. Here is a typical output of the session:

```
Collecting tensorflow
  Downloading tensorflow-2.8.0-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl (438.0 MB)
     -------------------------- ------------- 292.0/438.0 MB 3.7 MB/s eta 0:00:40
```

My pip is the latest as required by tensorflow.

Any ideas how to go past this point?

Comment: I rebooted my machine once and retried it the next day when it worked. Not sure whether it was some kind of network / transient issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting my answer in case some run into similar problem and it helps them. In my case I rebooted my machine once and retried it the other day when it worked fine. Haven't narrowed down whether it was some network / transient issue.